# Showing this family of functions to be equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $f_{n}: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we define
$g_{n}(x)=\int^{1}_{0} \frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt$. I want to show that this sequence $\mathscr{G}=(g_{n})$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence, that is, I need to check the conditions for Arzelà–Ascoli theorem . **I am having some trouble demonstrating equicontinuity for this family $\mathscr{G}$.**

The definition of equicontinuity that I am using is for any $\epsilon >0$, there  exists a $\delta>0$ where if $|x-y|< \delta$, then $|g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

It looks like a bit of a mess for me so far, we have that
\begin{align}
\mid g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y) \mid &= \mid \int^{1}_{0} \frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-x)^{1/3}}dt -\int^{1}_{0} \frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-y)^{1/3}}dt \mid \\\
&=  \mid \int^{1}_{0} (\frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-x)^{1/3}}-\frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-y)^{1/3}})dt \mid \\
&\leq   \int^{1}_{0} \mid (\frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-x)^{1/3}}-\frac{f_{n}(t)}{(t-y)^{1/3}}) \mid dt
\end{align}

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, we have that $f_{n}(t)$ attains a maximum $M$, so therefore

$\mid g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y) \mid  \leq M  \int^{1}_{0} \mid (\frac{1}{(t-x)^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{(t-y)^{1/3}}) \mid dt$

I am having trouble obtaining an estimate from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just evaluate the integrals and use the result to make a bound?

Comment: You don't need that $f_n$ attains a maximum (this would be bad, since you could have $M = M_n$ with $M_n \to \infty$). Your assumption yields $0 \leq f_n \leq 1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: We are given $0\le f_n(t)\le 1$ on $[0,1],$ hence it suffices to get a good estimate on

$$\int^{1}_{0} \mid \frac{1}{(t-x)^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{(t-y)^{1/3}} \mid dt =\int^{1}_{0} \frac{|(t-y)^{1/3}-(t-x)^{1/3}|}{|t-x|^{1/3}|t-y|^{1/3}}\,dt.$$

Because $u^{1/3}$ is continuous, hence uniformly continuous, on $[-1,1],$ the numerator will be small if $|x-y|$ is small. So we'll be done if we get a uniform estimate on

$$\int^{1}_{0} \frac{1}{|t-x|^{1/3}|t-y|^{1/3}}\, dt.$$

Use Cauchy-Schwartz for this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I will see what I can do from here. Thanks again.

Comment: @user135520  You unchecked this? Any reason?